# Trying to delete an entry in a database, recieve an sql error but can't work out how

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-delete

I am doing a really simple script to delete a row out of a database. I have done it before with almost identical code but for some reason this wont work!

Viewmessages.php has no problem running but when I try and delete the row using deletemessage.php I receive the an sql error, I only have one line of sql:

viewmessage (sending info to deletemessage.php):

```
echo "<a href='deletemessage.php?contactname=".$contactname."'>Delete</a>";
```

The following is the delete message code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['adminusername']))
{
header("Location:admin.php");
exit();
}


require "dbconn.php";

$contactname = $_GET['contactname'];

$query = "DELETE FROM message WHERE contactname =".$contactname;

$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: viewmessages.php");
?>
```

I cant work out what the error is! $contactname in the viewmessages.php file definately speaks of the primary key for the table!

Any Ideas?>

EDIT: I know that the problem lies with the contactname in the sql... for some reason it is not recieving it well, I did an echo to see what it thought the contactname was and it was correct. I then changed the variable and put in a string of one values in contactname and it deleted the row correctly... so the problem is the GET_['contactname'] but I am not sure what....

Comment: first guess would be that you need quotes in the query around the contact name - what's the exact error message that you get?

Comment: For future questions, please always include the SQL error message you received.  This one was easy for us to spot without seeing the error, but many aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose `$contactname` in quotes in the query, since it is a string.  But escape it first!  It is highly vulnerable to SQL injection the way it is now. I understand it may be an administrative page, but it is a very good habit to always observe, even when your users are trusted.  (Especially since Mr `O'Malley` would break the SQL statement when you tried to delete him)

```
$concatname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['contactname']);
$query = "DELETE FROM message WHERE contactname ='".$contactname . "'";
```

Always beware when deleting via a hyperlink.  Looks like you are checking for admin privileges before allowing this to execute, but be sure these links are not accessible to the broad Internet, [where they might get crawled.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx)

Comment: Thank you... I am teaching myself and am only in day 6 so am learning protection along the way... just trying to get to grips with how the code mechanics at the moment! thabnk you very much for you response works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess here? `$contactname` is a STRING. Therefore it must be in quotes in the query. Also, you want people to destroy your database, apparently.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `message` WHERE `contactname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($contactname)."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around a string you're inserting.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM message WHERE contactname ='".$contactname."'";
```

Note that this is MASSIVELY vulnerable to SQL injection. Someone could delete your entire database table with this code as it stands.

Comment: Thank you... I am teaching myself and am only in day 6 so am learning protection along the way... just trying to get to grips with how the code mechanics at the moment! thabnk you very much for you response!